# What would cause the Data Pallet's Data Source to not provide my form fields in Domino Designer Eclipse?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

For the last few days now, for some unknown reason, I'm unable to drag-n-drop fields from the Data Source field list onto a **brand new xpage** from scratch even.

The **Properties Panel** at the bottom has the Data set as

```
Other: dev\database.nsf
Form: someNotesForm
Data source name: document1
Default Action: Edit document
```

I'm open to ideas here.. thanks.

Comment: Help About Designer reveals this: 

Revision 20180125.1451-T00068SHF-FP10 (Release 9.0.1FP10 SHF68) Standard Configuration

Comment: Might be a bug in FP10? or are the fields in the form or in a subform ?

Comment: @umeli my fields are on the form;  I can still bind visible fields using the drop down found on the Properties - Data - Simple data binding.   

But what a pain in the derriere not being able to drag-n-drop from the Data Pallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling and upgrading to **SHF252** the Notes & Designer clients.   My Data Pallet is working again. Yay!